# Unhandled exception at 0x77e4bef7 in 1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std:out_of_range at memory location 0x0012fb8c

Tags: c++, memory, error-handling, outofrangeexception

There's something wrong in rows 25-30. I requested the existing index but get an error. I don't understand the problem, what's wrong?

```
    string *shells_host = new string[cnt];
    for(int i=0;i<cnt;i++)
    {
        shells_host[i] = LinkToHost(shells[i]);
        shells[i] = LinkToReq(shells[i],shells_host[i].size()+7);
    }
```

All code: http://codepaste.ru/10939/

Comment: Its array of string, same as shells_host

Comment: `func.h` is something that we don't know. So, no way to know if `LinkToHost` and `LinkToReq` (assuming they are defined in `func`) are correct. Why are you using an array of `string`s? Use a `vector`. return `string`s by value. Let RVO kick-in. And yes, you probably have a leak since my quick scan couldn't find a `delete [] shells_host;`.

Comment: Yes, but when using the vector is the same problem! http://codepaste.ru/10940/  -- func.h

Comment: Have you run your application in a debugger? Have you checked that all indexes are withing range of whatever array/vector/collection you are using?

Comment: We don't know what `LinkTohost()` or `LinkToReq()` do, but `shells_host[i].size()+7` certainly looks a bit fishy...  In any case, this should be easy to debug by stepping through the code.

Comment: Yes, I ran the debugger and saw a few strings of well handled, but then for some reason an error occurs

Comment: About `LinkToReq(shells[i],shells_host[i].size()+7);`, I can't say anything about `LinkToReq` since you don't show it anywhere, but what if some length of something inside is less (or more) than `shells_host[i].size()+7`?

Comment: These functions are cut off the link. First, in the shell fall line, then they are transformed into the domain and request

Comment: You might want to stick some debug output in there so you can see what the actual values stored in `shells` are. Any chance that one of them is under 7 characters long, for example?

Comment: No, this is a reference to a resource

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. A short string would cause an error, so you should be checking for short strings.

Answer (score 3):

You pass an empty string to the LinkToHost() and the call to url.substr(7) causes the exception.

Needless to say, that it takes a few minutes to run your code under debugger to figure out this.

Answer (score 0):

Either dive in with a debugger or break up the problem and add some debug print statements:

```
for(int i=0;i<cnt;i++)
{
    printf("i=%d, shells=%d", i, shells[i]);
    shells_host[i] = LinkToHost(shells[i]);

    int secondArg = shells_host[i].size()+7;
    printf("shells_host=%d, secondArg", shells_host[i], secondArg);
    shells[i] = LinkToReq(shells[i], secondArg);
}//to here
```

Comment: The program does not display the value of i, but why?

Comment: Thank you! It was my fail in testing!